# Change flow of static call (Java)

Tags: java, eclipse, static, static-methods

I have many instances of

```
Foo.a()
```

but now I want to split up calls to a() based on certain criteria. If possible I would like to keep the Foo.a() calls unchanged. Instead, perhaps Foo could become a factory that manages the flow and FooA and FooB could extend Foo. For example, in Foo:

```
private static Class<?> foo;

static {
     if (certain_criteria) {
        foo = SomeUtil.getClass("FooA");
     } else  {
         foo = FooB.class;
     }
     Object obj = foo.newInstance();
     o = (Foo) obj;
 }
...
public static void a() {
    o.a(); //And this should call either FooA.a() or FooB.a()
           //But a() should be accessed in a static way
}
```

I can't make a() in Foo non-static because then I'll have to change the 100+ calls throughout the project to Foo.a(). Is there a way around this? Or a better way to handle the flow?

I also tried to use foo to call a(), but that gives a compiler error because it is of type Class?>. If I change it to

```
Class<Foo>
```

then I get

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from Class<FooB> to Class<Foo>
```

Comment: Declare `foo` to have type `Class<? extends Foo>`.  Also, give it a better name, maybe "fooClass".

Comment: Note, too, that this only works if `Foo.a()` is invoking *instance* methods on `o`.  Static methods are not virtual.

Comment: Thanks, John. That does solve the type mismatch. However, I can't call any classes from Foo on foo. "The method a() is undefined for the type Class<capture#6-of ? extends Foo>

Comment: it sounds like you are trying to invoked a method on the `Class` object, as opposed to on an instance of the class -- in other words, on the `foo` of your example instead of on the `o`.  The only methods you can invoke on a `Class` object are those of class `Class`.  Those do include methods for reflective method invocation, but I suggest you not go there.  Give your subclasses an appropriate virtual method, and let `Foo.a()` invoke that method.

Comment: Thanks John! If you want to write up an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You propose using static method `Foo.a()` as a facade over selecting and invoking an appropriate implementation, in a configurable manner chosen by class `Foo`.  Your specific idea seems to rely on subclasses of `Foo` to implement the Strategy pattern for supporting `Foo.a()`.

You are conflating at least two separable pieces to this:

1. the strategy for implementing `Foo.a()`, and
2. the mechanism by which a specific strategy is chosen and instantiated.

In particular, although you may have reason to want to use subclasses of `Foo` to represent your strategies in the real code, no such reason is apparent in your example code.  Schematically, then, you seem to want something like this:

```
public class Foo {

    private static FooStrategy strategy = FooStrategyFactory.createStrategy();

    public static void a() {
        strategy.doA();
    }
}

interface FooStrategy {
    void doA();
}
```

You don't need to go all the way there, of course.  Your original idea was basically to let `Foo` itself serve in the place of `FooStrategy`, and to let a static initializer serve instead of a separate `FooStrategyFactory`.  There's nothing inherently wrong with that; I just pull it apart to more clearly show what role each bit serves.

You also expressed some specific implementation issues:

> If I change it to `Class<Foo>` then I get
>
> > Type mismatch: cannot convert from Class to Class

The equivalent in my scheme above would be declaring a variable of type `Class<FooStrategy>`, and attempting to assign to it a `Class<FooStrategyA>` representing a class that implements `FooStrategy`.  The correct type for a `Class` object that may represent any class whose instances are assignment-compatible with type `FooStrategy` is `Class<? extends FooStrategy>`.  That works whether `FooStrategy` itself is a class or an interface.

> I can't call any classes from Foo on foo. "The method a() is undefined for the type Class"

You seem to have been saying that you could not invoke static methods of class `Foo` on an object of type `Class<? extends Foo>`.  And indeed, you can't.  Objects of class `Class` have only the methods of class `Class`.  Although you can use them to reflectively invoke methods of the classes they represent, such methods are not accessible directly via the `Class` instance itself.  That issue does not arise directly in the scheme I presented, but it could arise in the factory or strategy implementations.

Moreover, static methods are not virtual.  They are bound at compile time, based on the formal type of the reference *expressions* on which they are invoked.  In order to apply the strategy pattern correctly, the needed strategy implementation methods need to be virtual: non-`private` and non-`static`.